# Nginx locations configuration for two directions

Tags: nginx, configuration, location

I have a little experience with configuring nginx server and here is my trouble. 
I am trying set correct locations. I have two directs: **address.com** and **address.com/api**.

For last direction(API) I have setted locations and it works fine. API is located in **/var/www/project/api** folder.

```
root /var/www/project;
index index.php;
server_name localhost;

location /api {
            try_files /api/$uri $uri/ /api/index.php?$query_string;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;                
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^/api/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_keep_conn on;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    }
```

Now I need implement root for address.com to **/var/www/project/website**. And here I have some troubles.

First thing, what I did I had written that:

```
 location / {
      alias /var/www/project/website/;
 }
```

And then I tried to add many different variants and here is my last note.

I have put it inside **location / {}**

```
       location ~ ^/(.+\.php)$ {
           alias /var/www/project/website/;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf; 
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
           fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
   }
```

In **/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf** file I have added

```
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And I get all time **403 Forbidden** or **404 Not found** or in nginx errors log is written that, for example, **/var/www/project/website/...** is not found.

Has somebody experience with nginx configuring and can tell, how to set **/website** location correct?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/src/website;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /test {
        try_files $uri $uri/test.html =404;
    }
    location /api/ {
        alias /var/www/src/api/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /pmants {
        root /var/www/src/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/pmants/(.+\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                root /var/www/src/;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* ^/pmants/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                root /var/www/src/;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.php {
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_cache off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```